# JavaScript links and SEO?

Tags: javascript, seo

First, take a look at this demo page: http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/seo-javascript-links.html

There is a menu on the page, and clicking on a menu item will display various links to other web-pages (that are part of the web-site). The link URLs are in this format:

```
www . foo . com / articles / XXX / descriptive-title-of-the-article
```

... where XXX is a three-digit ID of the given article.

This all seems OK, but there is one issue: all those links are created dynamically via JavaScript. Take a look at the source-code - at the bottom of the page there is a JavaScript variable (the `db` variable) which holds all the data which is used to generate the links.

I am using JavaScript because I don't want to use the server-side. I assume, in that case I would have to store the data inside a SQL database, and then  use C#/PHP/etc. to generate the links. However, this is not an option for me - I am oriented strictly towards the 
client-side.

BTW, if you want to see a more elaborate demonstration of JavaScript-generated links, go here - http://www.w3viewer.com - there are ~400 links on that page, all of which are generated dynamically via JavaScript.

***The question:***

Now, I like this approach - using JavaScript to generate links - however, a consequence of this approach is that search-engine crawlers won't register any of those links - they just "see" an empty page with no links (which is a SEO disaster, I assume).

So, I was wondering, how could I optimize this approach?

***Update (follow-up question):***

Couldn't I use a Google sitemap, to tell the Google crawler which web-pages exist on the web-site? That way I could keep the front-page (the demo above) as it is (with no static links), and the crawler would use the sitemap to crawl all the web-pages of my web-site.

I don't know anything about Google sitemaps yet, but I am wondering why no one suggested them. Could they be a solution to my issue?

Comment: Just wondering, what will users without javascript see? I get **no** links when I disable JS. Any why don't you want to have your links generated server side?

Comment: Marko, JS is the standard today. Nobody expects people to write websites compatible with no-JS browsers.

Comment: @Marko Users without JavaScript will see nothing, obviously :) Try visiting the W3 Viewer with JavaScript disabled - there is nothing there ... Also, try visiting the W3 Viewer with IE, and check out the redirection :p

Comment: Related : http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/how-can-i-create-links-in-javascript-that-are-crawlable-by-search-engines

Comment: @Kos - You just stick to that rule then wonder why Search Engines have no idea what pages you have on your site.

Comment: @Marko I am a front-end developer. I have no time to additionally  master a server-side language. I'd rather perfect my JavaScript skills further. Also, if we take search-engines out of the equation, my belief is that my approach (using JavaScript) is far superior than a server-side approach (because JavaScript is superior to any server-side language). I am not going to spend my time learning inferior languages just because of search-engine crawlers.

Comment: @Šime - `Javascript is superior to any server-side language.` Are you freakin high??? So as a front-end developer, you're going to disregard all concerns with SEO and users without Javascript just because you think that JS should be used to generate links? You could EASILY do that with a server side-language and I really suggest you look up an MVC solution such as ASP.NET MVC or Rails. They're specifically designed with friendly URLs in mind. *P.S. Ignorance will not get you far in this field, buy a book on ANY server-side language, read it so at least you know what happens behind the scenes.*

Comment: @Marko I am **very much** concerned about SEO. But when it comes to generating and manipulating dynamic web-pages, JavaScript is superior to any server-side language - that is what I meant. Server-side languages probably are superior in other aspects.

Comment: @Sime - No, generating dynamic web-pages should happen on the server side, with a connection to a database or another data source (i.e. XML). Javascript should be used unobtrusively and **only to improve** the user-experience. Your site however, should still (mostly) work without it.

Comment: @Marko Should dynamic web-pages be generated on the server-side? Well, generally yes, although there are exceptions, of course. But this is not my point. My point is that JavaScript can to it **better** than any other server-side language.

Comment: @Šime OK, so you have taken helpful comments and turned this into an argument over languages? What is the point? JavaScript is a useful language for certain purposes. However, search engine crawlers don't execute JavaScript. Therefore, you should reserve JavaScript for stuff that does not matter to search engine crawlers, and present links etc in HTML. Whether you do that dynamically via a server side language or use a development tool that generates static HTML pages depends on the nature of your site.

Comment: @Šime Post another question here and call it **Dynamic pages** *(Server-side or Client-side)?* See what kind of responses you get. Argument closed.

Comment: I don't want to start an outrageous debate about this, but you don't know any server side language well, but you state that JavaScript can do this better? The only exception where you don't have to provide a web page that doesn't work without JavaScript I can think of is that when a web page is not used as a worldly-readable document, but as a web application (preferably only used in-house), like Gmail; and even Gmail has an HTML-only interface.

Comment: @Downvoters: please provide an explanation why you do so; you can disagree with the OP's approach, but this is not where downvotes are intended for; they should be used when a question is unclear.

Comment: @Sinan @Marcel Yea, I should be more careful when stating my beliefs. "Thou shalt keep thy religion to thyself." - Carlin :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like what you really need to do is to generate the HTML using templates before deployment using something like [Template::Toolkit](http://perldoc.perl.org/Template)'s `ttree`. Then, you can keep your database on your *development* machine. No need for JavaScript.

Here is a simplified example:

```
[%- 
db = {
    Foo => [
        { id => "001", title => "First article" },
        { id => "002", title => "Another article" },
        { id => "003", title => "Yet another article" },
    ], 
    Bar => [
        { id => "004", title => "First article in this category" },
        { id => "005", title => "Another article in bar" },
        { id => "006", title => "Third bar article" },
    ],
    Baz => [
        { id => "007", title => "Baz article No. 1" },
        { id => "008", title => "The second Baz article" },
        { id => "009", title => "The last article" },
    ],
}
-%]

[%- FOR category IN db.keys -%]

<h2>[%- category -%]</h2>

[%- articles = db.$category -%]

[%- FOR article IN articles -%]

<p>Article: <a href="http://www.example.com/articles/[%- article.id -%]/">
    [%- article.title -%]</a></p>

[%- END -%]
[%- END -%]
```

```
C:\Temp> tpage t.html
```

```
<h2>Bar</h2>

<p>Article: <a href="http://www.example.com/articles/004">First article in this
category</a></p>

<p>Article: <a href="http://www.example.com/articles/005">Another article in bar
</a></p>

<p>Article: <a href="http://www.example.com/articles/006">Third bar article</a><
/p>

<h2>Baz</h2>

<p>Article: <a href="http://www.example.com/articles/007">Baz article No. 1</a><
/p>
```

…

Comment: @Sinan I was thinking about that, too. However, there is a considerable difference in size between the database entry - `{ id: "001", title: "First article" }` - and HTML output - `<a href="http://www.foo.com/articles/001/first-article">The first article</a>`. With 100 links I would have an additional 10k on my page. I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Well, you could use: `<a href="/a/001/first-article">The first article</a>` which should cut down the size some (assuming these articles are on the same server). Also, if `gzip` compression is turned on, that extra 10K should not be noticeable at all (should test this;-)

Comment: @Sinan Thanks for the example, but I can easily generate the HTML code via JavaScript (if I would choose your approach and "pre-compile" the HTML code).

Comment: @Šime Assuming this is not a dynamic site, the benefits of generating static HTML pages (they can still have behaviors, just no generating the basic content of the page via JavaScript), you get two benefits: 1. Search engines can crawl your site which is more valuable to you than any few K of additional storage space or transfer time *and* your page becomes usable on more devices (such as my very old Nokia cell phone with an ancient version of Opera installed).

Comment: @Sinan +1 Your 1. argument is very convincing :)

Comment: @Šime – I highly agree with Sinan: this is really the only way that you can be sure a search engine can see your page. I know in some situations even a few K can be costly, but you'll get a lot of benefits from the server side approach. Just because JavaScript *can* do it (even rather well) doesn't mean it should be used to do it.

Comment: @Marcel The other way is server-side JavaScript (like node.js). I will probably use one of these two approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you're avoiding the server-side because you prefer JavaScript to those other languages, you could always use node.js on the server.  There's already [a jQuery Templates view engine for node.js](https://github.com/kof/node-jqtpl) that works with Express, so you can even use the same template on client or server.

Unrelated: You shouldn't use the "latest" reference to jQuery on the CDN (i.e. 1.4 vs 1.4.4). Those requests [are served with a very short expires header](http://paulirish.com/2009/caching-and-googles-ajax-libraries-api/), which is a big performance disadvantage.  At that point, it's faster for return visitors if you just use a self-hosted copy.

Comment: +1 Yes, I am interested in node.js. Using JavaScript on the server-side would be a great solution to my problem. However, I will have to look into it further, since I currently have no experience with node.js. Could you just tell me what kind of hosting service I would need for it. I currently have ASP.net hosting...

Comment: I can vouch for it being very easy to set up on a VPS running Ubuntu.  You can run it on Windows using Cygwin, but I don't know how stable that is compared to the directly supported environments. Also check out http://no.de

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thing to note, if you include links in your site map which cant be got at via crawling you site you will be marked down within the search engines.

As these pages are seen as doorway pages which are against the t&c of most major search engines, also with no referring URL's they will get a very low score and even if they do get indexed, they wont rank very well.

Comment: +1 Yea, it seems that using just a sitemap is not a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

use both js and href ...
the trick is simply to have to the site works with href that is what google bot will see
at the same time js click handler will be used if browser support it.

of course return false from the handler also stops the href.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<noscript> All your anachor links here</noscript>` which means that the crawlers and users with javascript off will see the links too. You should never forget about users without javascript, and base functionality of a page solely on javascript (without providing noscript alternative), which will also benefit you in SEO sense.

Comment: Guard That would mean that I would have to generate those anchors on the server-side which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Using sitemap would help your pages to be able to crawl by Google but Google ranks you up by page title+content. Also if you use permalinks (you are already using) and page title also exists as h1 tag inside body that would be great.

You would better to put some content as html inside body. You should enrich page functionality with javascript. However Google pages are fully javascript it doesn't like javascript as well. It is the ruler and until it identifies javascript content we all should adopt the rules.

If you would add a sitemap you may use below script.

To top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

Repeated url lists. Date with time zone, priority 0 to 1, default is 0.5:

```
<url>
<loc>page url</loc>
<lastmod>2011-02-06T03:13:29+02:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
<priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
```

Ending:

```
</urlset>
```